What parts should I replace on my electric water heater?
I posted a question about my Resistance 606 Electric Water Heater the other day with a picture of what it looked like.
Now I'm asking about the bottom panel because it's just as bad as the top was. What parts should I replace? What are they called?


I would not bother replacing parts.  That heater is looking like it is on its last leg and will start leaking soon.  Requiring a replacement.  So save your money from buying more parts.

Yes but I don't have the money to actually buy a new water heater and the rust cane from one of the pipes having a Crack in it and we didn't notice that anything was wrong with it until we actually heard the water spraying  because the pipe cracking more that is why it looks like it's older then what it is??

If just surface rust and you clean/paint it(the tank itself) maybe get parts.  Rust eats metal and those tanks are not that thick, plus they hold water under pressure.  You really want to look at the bottom, where the water went and stayed.

The rust didn't come from a crack in the pipe. The rust came from a rusty water heater.  It's not worth repairing. Water heaters don't last that long in the first place. Use it until it fails. Save your pennies in the meantime.

The serial number on that water heater shows it's 20 years old. The expected lifetime of a water heater is half that.

Habitat for Humanity.  Water heaters are like WWII destroyers. They last a lot longer if you change the anode regularly, but no one does.

It's called the thermostat 4500 watts.you can get the top and bottom thermostat from walmart for about 20 bucks each.it will get you down the road for awhile. How long, who knows, depends on how bad the rust is. Sometimes pictures can be decieving.

If it's  just surface rust it's probably ok.  but be sure to replace the anode at the specified interval to prevent the tank from rusting inside.
Replace the parts that are not working...  take the broken part with you I find that "one of these but not busted" is universally understood when buying parts retail.
There's no way that we can test the thermostat and heating element over the internet, you'll have to determine if they are working correctly.

Think about how much flood damage will cost if the tank fails completely. I suspect you will find that you can't afford not to replace the whole tank. If you can't afford a new one right now, try looking for a used one that is young enough and in good enough condition to last a couple years while you save up for a proper replacement.
You're already on borrowed time.
